# Using the unanswered button

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

It seems odd, but that button (the one next to the badges button) does not really return a list of unanswered questions. While on the default subview, that is in fact the case, when I switch to the sort by votes, there are many questions there that have answers.

Whats going on?

Similar story when I filter by my tags and newest (i.e. just the default view works properly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the "No Answers" tab, that is the one that has questions with literally no answers.

The rest of the "Unanswered" view tabs are really lists of questions with answers that have no upvotes or have not been accepted.

There are plenty of questions on that list with answers, but as they have no upvotes it means other users did not think it worked or solved the issue, leaving the question still unanswered.

Comment: seem rather confusing to change the meaning of unanswered....

Comment: I'm not fond of it either...

Comment: @random My draft was sitting here since this morning, and now that I finally come around to sending it you fix this answer :-(

Answer (score 2):

Since *anybody* can reply to a question, the system only considers a question to have *answers* if the reply

- Is accepted
- Has been upvoted (Score > 1)

No reply to any question shown in that tab has a positive vote total, so neither the person asking considers the post to answer the question, nor do more users consider it an answer than down voted that post.

Comment: The different standards thing still bothers me.

Comment: @soandos What's the *other* standard? Displaying the answer count next to a list entry?

Comment: Standard 1: no answers posted. Standard 2: no upvoted, marked as accepted answers posted.

Comment: @soandos Who's using "Standard 1"?

Comment: Ouch, just realized, its no answers, and unanswered. I should be more careful when I read ;)

Comment: @soandos Someone giving you an answer does not mean your question is answered ;-) That's where *unanswered* comes from, and the system uses votes and accept marks as indicators that an answer is actually *answering* the question, at least for somebody.

Comment: Now, I see and feel foolish, but thanks